# Using git with multiple branches at once

Tags: git

Does git support a view where different files come from different branches?

Here is my setup -- I have a simple git branch structure with master being used for all development and installs at the client site. Since the client setup is different from my setup, I have a small number of a files on a different branch, called "my_company_name". Files that specify hostnames, for example, would be in this category.

What I'd like to do is work on the master branch, but get specific files from my_company_name. I understand that I could accomplish the same thing by:

1. git checkout my_company_name
2. git merge origin master

but I would need to specify 'origin master' each time I push, or the files will be going to my_company_name. If I do the opposite:

1. git checkout master
2. git merge origin my_company_name

then I would need to make changes in the site-specific files before installing at the client site.

How does git support this?

Comment: Not an answer, but it would be very trivial to write a script to check the current branch and do that for you then you can add it as an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [repo](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) to manage a work space with a few git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at smudge/clean scripts instead of branches for this. See the git attributes chapter in the progit.org/book. Or just use plain scripts.